# How to save a .get Gatling response to a file

Tags: scala, gatling

I've recorded a script of a web application using the Gatling recorder.  I would like to save the responses from the .get  calls to a file to verify the responses. I've done plenty of searches but I have not found any specific examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Save and check response bodies" checkbox on the Recorder's configuration pane, as visible in the [official documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/http/recorder/).

Comment: I have that checked but where does it store the responses after the script runs?

Comment: In the `resources` directory.

Comment: Thank you! I found it.